# How to replace last occurence of a character?

Tags: text-processing, replace

I have a file composed by lines like these ones:

```
199240050;0180209199240050;0
199240241;0180209199240241;0
199240207;0180209199240207;0
199240400;0180209199240400;0
```

I should replace last number with "Active" if it is "0", Or "Inactive" if it is "1".

I've tried with `sed` but the occurrence of ";0" in the middle of the line gets changed too.

It should be used in a linux bash script.

---

I tried [the solution given by DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391661/22222) but it fails:

```
$ sed 's/0$/active/;s/1$/inactive/'  myLines.txt
800600346                078136521                       active
```

While the format of the input file should not change.

The second solution appends ";active" at the end, without replacing:

```
$ awk -F\; 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} { if( $3 == 1 ) { print $1,$2,"inactive" } else { print $1,$2,"active" } }'  myLines.txt
800010654                0295445503                     0;;active
```

And [George Vasiliou's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391710/22222) also fails:

```
$ awk '$NF?$NF="active":$NF="inactive"' FS=';' OFS=';' myLines.txt
active
active
active
active
```

Comment: None of these will change the format. Are you sure the example you show correctly represents your file? Could you have created the file on Windows?

Comment: Have you checked for possible carriage return `\r` line endings ??

Comment: My fault, the input file format had been overwritten after several tries and I ignored it, I'm really sorry for that. The solution with sed given by SopeGhoti works greatly !!! Many thanks to everyone !

Comment: You need to accept Ghoti solution as an answer to your question with the green tick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your given data in a file called `input`:

```
$ awk -F\; 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} { if( $3 == 1 ) { print $1,$2,"inactive" } else { print $1,$2,"active" } }' input
199240050;0180209199240050;active
199240241;0180209199240241;active
199240207;0180209199240207;active
199240400;0180209199240400;active
```

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\;0$/active/;s/\;1$/inactive/' input
199240050;0180209199240050;active
199240241;0180209199240241;active
199240207;0180209199240207;active
199240400;0180209199240400;active
```

Comment: Would be better as `s/;0$/;active/;s/;1$/;inactive/'` to avoid replacing `foo;10` with `foo;1active`

Answer (score 4):

One more awk, more idiomatic :

```
$ awk '$NF?$NF="inactive":$NF="active"' FS=';' OFS=';' file
```

Last field $NF is evaluated . If found zero then Last Field $NF is changed to "active" , otherwise is changed to "inactive".

Print is omitted since will be performed by default.

Alternative , even more idiomatic by using ternary operation in variable assignment :

```
$ awk '$NF=($NF?"inactive":"active")' FS=';' OFS=';' file
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach! You can make these together `FS=OFS=';'`

Comment: This is reversed from the Q: $3 (implicitly !=0 and in fact ==1) should be "Inactive". @αғsнιη: that works in the script (especially in `BEGIN{ }`) but not as pseudo-file commandline arguments.

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks! Chaining FS and OFS together is allowed only within a BEGIN block , not "externally" after the main code....

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeap, good point. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+(?!.*\d)/$& ? "Inactive" : "Active"/e' < file
```

Replaces the first sequence of digits that is not followed by any digit with "Inactive" if it's 0 or "Active" otherwise.